# Converted breadboard to PCB will not work despite being exactly the same

Tags: pcb, atmega

Hi guys I had a breadboard design set up using an ATMEGA328P-PU and ESP8266-01 and a PIR sensor. I replicated this circuit exactly and it will not work.

First of all I started a new PCB circuit and left out the ESP as I had found out the the ATMEGA was actually not outputting of port B5  when motion was detected.

I have done continuity tests and everything seems fine, when I wave my hand in front of the PIR I can detect using a multimeter that the it is working and can also detect off pin AC0 that that is being detected by the ATMEGA. What isn't happening is on detection output from port B5 to turn on an LED and Port B4 to turn on the ESP, no out put is coming out of those pins at all. I have checked with multimeter and 4.89v is going into bot VCC and AVCC correctly ground is connected to pin 8 and pin 22 (VCC and AVCC pin 7 and pin 20) I have a 16 clock with 2 x 22 capacitors connected to ground, 10k resistor connected to pin 1 and vcc. Power is a 12v mains plug going through a 10uF and then a 5v regulator and a final 10uf.

This is exactly the same setup as the breadboard which I have had functioning for some time yet it will not work any ideas please guys.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATED IMAGES WITH THE HELP OF THE COMMUNITY:

[image]

[image]

Comment: First of all you should give us a schematic to help you and layout as  well.

Comment: I dont have I explained all the connections above I will take a couple of photos of the layout.

Comment: Updated with photos now.

Comment: Take a loupe and inspect the holes for leftover copper wires, and the space between soldered lanes for solder bridges. And check wthere the circuit is eactly the same. Watch out for mirroring errors. Check that the correct uC pins get power.

Comment: Where are the decoupling caps on supply into the IC? I would remove those 2 white wires and jumper the ends of the caps directly to the black wire next to them.

Comment: I have checked the circuit all should be correct,  I have done continuity tests the holes for the atmega are fine there is no current connecting before and after the holes. All continuity tests were successful nothing out of place :S  Decoupling caps are at the bottom right next to the power supply as mentioned above 2x 10uf one after the supply and one after the voltage regulator. I will change the caps wiring back however they were as you mentioned the first time round, I changed them to see if it made any difference. Will be back soon thanks for the reply.

Comment: This is not a good layout for a uC.The decoupling caps should be close as possible to the IC and traces should be kept small.What is the output of the PIR sensor ? (Analog,Digital)

Comment: I may be wrong but looking at the bottom photo, it looks like you only cut the copper under the DIP chip. It looks like everything that is installed vertically (caps, resistor, LED, etc.) are shorted out by the copper strips.

Comment: Decoupling caps are typically ceramics and are placed right at the IC pins. Anything else is not a decoupling cap.

Comment: Output of sensor is 3.26 roughly. @DoxyLover Yes but nothing is touching. Brhans could you be more specific of what I need to change then please, I just expected the breadboard version to work the same on PCB.

Comment: Whoever marked it down I feel that is a bit rude, I have researched and not found my answer so came here to ask for assistance.

Comment: Can anyone help please? I have made all the changes in this post and updated the photos above but still nothing the sensor output can be detected using multimeter on pin a0 but the output on b5 and b4 are not working and the led does not light up.

Comment: I see lots of swarf around your drill cuts. Clean up the cuts with a knife to make sure there are no shorts. Unsolder the ATMEGA and put a DIP socket in for it, then you can easily remove it for testing or reprogramming. With the MCU removed, test continuity of all the connections on the board (making sure they match the circuit diagram) then apply power and check that it is on the correct pins of the socket. If you have corrected all errors and the MCU tests out OK on a breadboard but it _still_ doesn't work, put a 'blink LED'  program into it and see if you can get _that_ to work.

Comment: Thank you I don't have a DIP socket at the moment I have done continuity all over the board and it seems like all is good, someone mentioned earlier down that the chip may of shorted, and I remembered on my first one I soldered some wires in to the chip to attach my programmer and it was not found, is it possible that when there were no holes cut between the clock caps that it shorted the chip? I am starting again fresh now with a new board and new chip it is all working as expected on the breadboard about to start the new circuit.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

I don't see any evidence that the tracks beneath the XTAL's capacitors are cut.

Also I don't see any power supply decoupler caps on the pins of the device.

Comment: Good catch - the XTAL is simply being shorted to Gnd... Similarly the vertically oriented resistors don't have breaks in the tracks beneath them.

Comment: Ahh ok so the after the crystal and the first pins of the caps there needs to be a break before the second pin ? Not sure what you mean about decoupling pins on the power supply they are at the bottom right as i mentioned and did not have them on the breadboard. What would be best to use and where to put them ?

Thank you for helping by the way, great to get quick responses.

Comment: Decouplers are usually 100 nF and go directly close to the chip's pins.

Comment: 0.1uF decoupling caps should be as physically close to the VCC and GND pins as possible.  Some people even put the cap over the ic. The placement here seems a bit far. But the shorting issue is the most important.

Comment: Ok thank you I have updated the images above, I have cut the track and continuity tested and that is fine now, but still not working, should I replace that 101 capacitor for a 100 and place it just above the black wire connecting ground to vcc on the left of the black wire?

Comment: @AKB what about the resistors and the LEDs - are those tracks cut too? I don't know what a 101 capacitor is and realistically I've kind of finished advising on this to any great extent.

Comment: My ceramic capacitors have 100, 101,102,103 and 104 printed on them. RE the resistors no I will do that now.

Comment: Hi have made all the changes suggested in this post but it still not working, would appreciate the help to get this resolved.

Comment: I'm just a guy a million miles away who pointed out some serious errors with tracks not being cut. Now you may have damaged your device (xtal pin which is an output being shorted indefinitely) or there may be other errors. I don't see your circuit, I don't understand your code, I don't even now if there's code in the chip or what you constitute as "not working". I can't help any further without driving to your house or you sending the board to me. I have pointed out several things wrong, now you find the remainder. Visual inspection is where you begin.

Comment: The code works fine as I have mentioned this functions fine on breadboard the issue has to be something with the circuit posted above. How it is suppose to work is exactly as mentioned, when the sensor detects motion it switches pin b5 and b4 one to power the LED and one to turn on ESP which is not on at the moment as there is no output on b5 or b4 so this is the issue I am trying to solve. on the new photos do you see anything that would be shorting it or anything wrong, the answer lies in those images, I am new to this type of development but I do know that the issue is with my circuit above

Comment: Keep reading my final previous and penultimate comment.

Comment: And here was me thinking support forums were a place to find support.

Comment: @AKB What makes you think this is a support forum? This is a question and answer site where answers are provided by volunteers. We have nothing to do with the any of the companies that produced or sold you any of the parts.

Comment: It is a place to find help with electronics no ? Hence I said support